# SSIS fill in Null Value with Non-Null Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, script-task

I'm currently able to get this type of output from a flat file after running a script component in SSIS:

[image: Current Output]

My goal is to fill in the rest of the column with the same serial number like this:

[image: Goal Output]

I tried to do this by setting it a variable and using a derived column, but the variable isn't set til after the data flow. Also the script only reads line by line so I don't see an obvious way to do this simple task.

Is there a way to create a column in the script and give it a default value of the serial number? Or is there a way for use a SQL command to update the Null values Where the column is Not Null?

Comment: Sure. You use an update statement. Update YourTable Set SerialNumber = whatever where SerialNumber IS NULL. But from what you posted those don't look like NULL, they look like empty strings.

Comment: @SeanLange When using SSIS and the ACE/JET drivers, Empty Cells will be imported as a *`NULL`*, not `''`. To the OP, personally, if you can define the order of the data after import, I would do this in your staging table instead. it's much easier there than doing a Script task. **Much** easier.

Comment: This is before I'm inserting it to a table. This is just the output of what my script is able to generate from a text file. Also they're blank cause I made the example in Excel.

Comment: Can't see your images, but maybe make another table. Import to table 1, update with serial number, then continue with your next steps using this staging table as the source.

Comment: I could do staging table with a trigger. My only issue is I have multiple files like this, and the unique identifier is the serial number. So I can't join on an inserted pseudo table to ensure I'm only updating the values I just imported.

Comment: From experience, when importing data from SSIS or any ETL process, loading firstly to a staging table is a great idea. There's nothing wrong with doing it, and there are some things that are much more easily done at different stages. It's not uncommon for an ETL process to really be a ELT process, and you shouldn't be "afraid" to change the order in which you do things to achieve the end goal.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Still very new to the game and figured I should minimize as many tables as possible.

Comment: I can't see images, but to change a null to a value I would just use a derived column. ISNULL(Test_Column) ? Null_Value : Test_Column

Comment: How is 123 chosen as default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this design in order to perform what you need (feel free to simplify it, tested with your input data) :
[image]

1. Read your source
2. Multicast
3. Aggregate on the column you want the max
   value (serial number)
4. create a derived column with a constant value
       ( 1 for example)
5. sort the set on the constant value
6. Merge your two set with a full join using the constant key
7. import data into the destination table and use the new aggregated
   column to fill the Serial number column

Answer (score -1):

Update statement after the data is loaded to a table:

```
update table 
set column = (select top 1 column from table where column is not null) 
where column is null
```

Comment: I'd advise caution against this. The OP seems to imply that they are loading data to a table that may already contain data (or have multiple sets). doing this method would `UPDATE` **every** *`NULL`* value with a **random** (you have no `ORDER BY` in your subquery using the `TOP 1`) non-*`NULL*` value of the same column. This could make the data very wrong.

Comment: This what I was afraid of as well. Normally on my triggers I use the INSERTED pseudo table ensure I don't accidentally mess with good data. But because my serial number isn't populated on insert, I can't really do that.